# What is the erlang regex equivalent of this?

Tags: regex, erlang

The subject of my regex is

```
"Digest realm=\"Protected Area\", nonce=\"MTQzNTMwMDI5OSA2ZmIxYWEzYzNkZjQzNmVlZDdiMjU1ZjZjNzQwYjJkNA==\", opaque=\"610a2ee688cda9e724885e23cd2cfdee\", qop=\"auth\""
```

The following regex works for me in Ruby. http://rubular.com/r/m3SRmHUd5V

```
/([\w\s]+)=\\"([\w\s]+)/
```

However, I am unable to findout how to do the same in Erlang. I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
RegexS = "([\w\s]+)=\\\"([\w\s]+)"

re:run(Subject,RegexS, [global, {capture, first, list}]).
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to escape the regex properly after storing it in a string? Like in Java, I guess Erlang would need to escape first for string, then for regex. So you need `\\w` for example.

Comment: I'm sorry--why have you tagged this question with Elixir?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci thanks for correcting me. Yes, it shouldn't be on elixir. Corrected it now. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape **all** backslashes.

```
1> Subject = "Digest realm=\"Protected Area\", nonce=\"MTQzNTMwMDI5OSA2ZmIxYWEzYzNkZjQzNmVlZDdiMjU1ZjZjNzQwYjJkNA==\", opaque=\"610a2ee688cda9e724885e23cd2cfdee\", qop=\"auth\"".
"Digest realm=\"Protected Area\", nonce=\"MTQzNTMwMDI5OSA2ZmIxYWEzYzNkZjQzNmVlZDdiMjU1ZjZjNzQwYjJkNA==\", opaque=\"610a2ee688cda9e724885e23cd2cfdee\", qop=\"auth\""
2> RegexS = "([\\w\\s]+)=\\\"([\\w\\s]+)".
"([\\w\\s]+)=\\\"([\\w\\s]+)"
3> re:run(Subject,RegexS, [global, {capture, first, list}]).
{match,[["Digest realm=\"Protected Area"],
        [" nonce=\"MTQzNTMwMDI5OSA2ZmIxYWEzYzNkZjQzNmVlZDdiMjU1ZjZjNzQwYjJkNA"],
        [" opaque=\"610a2ee688cda9e724885e23cd2cfdee"],
        [" qop=\"auth"]]}
4> io:format("~p => /~s/~n", [RegexS, RegexS]).
"([\\w\\s]+)=\\\"([\\w\\s]+)" => /([\w\s]+)=\"([\w\s]+)/
ok
5>
```

But you don't have to backslash `"` because `"` has no special meaning in regexp.

```
5> RegexS2 = "([\\w\\s]+)=\"([\\w\\s]+)".                   
"([\\w\\s]+)=\"([\\w\\s]+)"
6> re:run(Subject,RegexS2, [global, {capture, first, list}]).
{match,[["Digest realm=\"Protected Area"],
        [" nonce=\"MTQzNTMwMDI5OSA2ZmIxYWEzYzNkZjQzNmVlZDdiMjU1ZjZjNzQwYjJkNA"],
        [" opaque=\"610a2ee688cda9e724885e23cd2cfdee"],
        [" qop=\"auth"]]}
7> v(-1) =:= v(3).
true
8> io:format("~p => /~s/~n", [RegexS2, RegexS2]).            
"([\\w\\s]+)=\"([\\w\\s]+)" => /([\w\s]+)="([\w\s]+)/
ok
9>
```